# Can I get more gas pressure then I started with?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

The image shows constant gas at 2 psi being released in 55" depth of water. Gas will rise due to it being less dense than water. If gas continues being added into the closed system at 2 psi will it begin compressing itself? If so, is it possible to get more than 2 psi gas at the top? If I can get 2psi or more it seems plausible to recycle the pressurized gas right back into the bottom of the system.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is the water tank sealed?  In general the answer here will be no.

The air in the gas supply has to be at a greater pressure than the water or it won't be released.  The water pressure at that point will be $$P = P_0 + \rho g h$$

The 55" of water gives almost 2psi.  Any pressure of the gas at the top of the tank increases that pressure.  If you have 1psi gas at the top, then you have 3psi at the inlet level and the air won't release.

The gas at the top of the tank is pressurizing *both* sides, not just the air tank.

Comment: In an open tank, would the gas have lost it's pressure once it reaches the top?

Comment: @SpacemanSOB, the gas loses pressure all the way up the water column.